# Latex : bibliography with `natbib` package

Tags: reference, latex, bibliography

I am trying to write my report and I have this problem with `natbib` package. 
I am using overleaf and I am getting the same error:

> LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.
>
> See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation. Type  H
>     for immediate help.  ...
>
> ```
>                                                l.168 \bibliography
>                {references}
> ```

What i am doing wrong? 
This my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish, es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage[journal=jacs]{chemstyle}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[stable]{footmisc}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
%Paquetes necesarios para tablas
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xtab}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{colortab}

%Paquete para el manejo de las unidades
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{mode=text, output-decimal-marker = {,}, per-mode = symbol, qualifier-mode = phrase, qualifier-phrase = { de }, list-units = brackets, range-units = brackets, range-phrase = --}
\DeclareSIUnit[number-unit-product = \;] \atmosphere{atm}
\DeclareSIUnit[number-unit-product = \;] \pound{lb}
\DeclareSIUnit[number-unit-product = \;] \inch{"}
\DeclareSIUnit[number-unit-product = \;] \foot{ft}
\DeclareSIUnit[number-unit-product = \;] \yard{yd}
\DeclareSIUnit[number-unit-product = \;] \mile{mi}
\DeclareSIUnit[number-unit-product = \;] \pint{pt}
\DeclareSIUnit[number-unit-product = \;] \quart{qt}
\DeclareSIUnit[number-unit-product = \;] \flounce{fl-oz}
\DeclareSIUnit[number-unit-product = \;] \ounce{oz}
\DeclareSIUnit[number-unit-product = \;] \degreeFahrenheit{\SIUnitSymbolDegree F}
\DeclareSIUnit[number-unit-product = \;] \degreeRankine{\SIUnitSymbolDegree R}
\DeclareSIUnit[number-unit-product = \;] \usgallon{galón}
\DeclareSIUnit[number-unit-product = \;] \uma{uma}
\DeclareSIUnit[number-unit-product = \;] \ppm{ppm}
\DeclareSIUnit[number-unit-product = \;] \eqg{eq-g}
\DeclareSIUnit[number-unit-product = \;] \normal{\eqg\per\liter\of{solución}}
\DeclareSIUnit[number-unit-product = \;] \molal{\mole\per\kilo\gram\of{solvente}}
\usepackage{cancel}
%Paquetes necesarios para imágenes, pies de página, etc.
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[left=4cm,right=2cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor,soul,framed} %,caption
\colorlet{shadecolor}{yellow}
%Instrucción para evitar la indentación
%\setlength\parindent{0pt}
%Paquete para incluir la bibliografía
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=chem-acs,biblabel=dot]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

%Formato del título de las secciones

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\titleformat*{\section}{\bfseries\large}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\bfseries\normalsize}

%Creación del ambiente anexos
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{plaintop}
\newfloat{anexo}{thp}{anx}
\floatname{anexo}{Anexo}
\restylefloat{anexo}
\restylefloat{figure}

%Modificación del formato de los captions
\usepackage[margin=10pt,labelfont=bf]{caption}

%Paquete para incluir comentarios
\usepackage{todonotes}

%Paquete para incluir hipervínculos
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, 
            linkcolor = blue,
            urlcolor  = blue,
            citecolor = black,
            anchorcolor = blue]{hyperref}

\definecolor{mygreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{mygray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mymauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{darkWhite}{rgb}{0.94,0.94,0.94}
\usepackage{minted}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%Inicio del documento%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
%TXT
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please, clarify your question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution, the syntax should be:

```
\begin{document}
....
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```